# Ruby on Rails models relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database, rails-models

need some advice.
I'm doing a project on RoR, and do not sure what relationship between the models should I use. I've got three models - Users, Boards and Messages.
The beginning is pretty simple:
User has one Wall, and it belongs to the User, so I guess this should be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :board
end

class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

The last model is Messages and here comes my problem. Message belongs to User cause he writes it, but it also belongs to a Wall cause he writes it on a wall (and it can be Wall that belongs to other user).

I used the simple solution:

```
class Theme < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :board
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :board
      has_many :themes
end

class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      has_many :themes
end
```

But I not satisfy with it, and feel that it isn't perfect. I'm looking for a solution that will let me write thinks like:

```
user.themes.create(:board => @board)
```

(now it doesn't fill user_id field)

I hope that isn't a hard task for those who more experienced than me in Ruby on Rails model. I'll appreciate good advices, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For normal you use some authentification gem like devise. Then you have the current_user variable which includes the object of the user that is currently calling the action.

Then when a user creates the Topic you add one simple line to the controller to set the user:

```
@theme.user = current_user
```

You should also use a gem like cancan to manage the authorisation in a cenral file. Youl find a railscast here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

Comment: I understand that using this gems is a good practice, but I already have simple Users model that I have taken from Ruby on Rails tutorial of Michael Hartl. I can do what you're suggesting, but I looking for a solution in which your line will be unnecessary, as in a simple many to one relationship. thanks for help

Comment: You need to add some line that handles with this problem. There ist no secure alternative! Of cause you can ad a hidden field that supplies the user_id but then you give the controll over th euser to the client because he can manipulate all the data supplied via POST and GET!

Comment: Actually, in unexpected way my solution did work as I want it. Thank you for your advices I sure will implement them in the future.